# Can't login to spotify via libspotify on raspberry pi

Tags: spotify, raspberry-pi, libspotify

I'm using libspotify 12.1.103.gd51f6226 Release Linux-armv6-bcm2708hardfp on my Raspberry Pi and I think that everything worked out alright with the instruction in the readme.

I changed out appkey.c for my appkey as given by spotify but when I run the spshell example and try to login, I get an error

```
FATAL, TERMINATING: failed to log in to Spotify: Cannot connect to Spotify
Logged out
Exiting...
```

I'm sure that I'm using the correct username (I also tried email) and password (I also tried changing the password) and I've tried the jukebox example as well and get a similar error.  I'm able to log into the website and the windows app just fine.

The one place that I think that I might have gone wrong is:

```
After this, ensure your PKG_CONFIG_PATH is set tocd 
include the libspotify control file, and that the lib directory is
in the library search path.
```

I'm pretty sure that I did that okay and I don't get any errors during the build.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same exact problem, have you managed to solve this? I really don't want to switch to the soft float version of weezy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, which you can see from my comments on this question. For me it turned out to be a problem with my username which contains a non-ascii letter `ö`. But since my plan all along was to use [pyspotify](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyspotify/1.1) I managed to log in using their jukebox example and hardcoding my username where appropriate and adding the nice little `u` infront of it, and now I can login to spotify, see line ~460 in the jukebox example:

```
session_m = Jukebox(options.username, options.password, True)
```

Which i changed to this:

```
session_m = Jukebox(u"username_with_ö", options.password, True)
```

Now my problem is another which is that I can't access /dev/dsp but that is an entirerly different problem. :)

**EDIT**
`apt-get install alsa-oss` solve the above mentioned problem, my raspberry is now playing music!

Answer (score 0):

I can compile and login.

What I did was to simply extract the tar.gz to 
And then..

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev libreadline-dev
cd <libspotify folder>/share/doc/libspotify/examples
vim appkey.c
```

And then add the application key that you generate. But that seemed to work for you.

```
make LIBSPOTIFY_PATH=../../../..
spshell/spshell
```

Then I can login and do a lot of things, I haven't tried any audio yet since I don't have any speakers/headphones available.

If you install it instead using

```
cd <libspotify folder>
make install prefix=/usr/local
```

as described in the README also run

```
sudo ldconfig
```

to update the library cache, and then just do a normal compile.

```
cd <libspotify folder>/share/doc/libspotify/examples
make
```

If you suspect that you have compiled stuff the wrong way, do a "make clean" first.

Don't know if this is to any help but that is how far I have come.

Comment: What version of raspbian are you running? The one with soft-float or the one with hard-float? I.e can you run java on your raspberry?